# Show that $x^a \le x$ for $x \in (0,1)$ and $a \ge 1$

Tags: real-analysis

Using the definition $$x^a = e^{a \log x} $$ is there any way to show that for $x \in (0,1)$ and $a \ge 1$ that $x^a \le x$.

Using the traditional definition of $x^a$ ($x^a$ = $x$ multiplied by itself $a$ times) the result is obvious. I was wondering if there was any simple way to show this result using the above definition. Any hints would be welcome.

Comment: Hint: $x = e^{\log x}$.

Comment: This is equivalent to showing $x^{a-1}\leq 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the requested definition of

$$x^a = e^{a\log x} \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

note that

$$x^a - x = e^{a\log x} - e^{\log x} = e^{\log x}\left(e^{\left(a - 1\right)\log x} - 1\right) \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

Now,

$$e^{\log x} = x \gt 0 \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

Also, it's given that

$$a \ge 1 \Rightarrow  a - 1 \ge 0 \tag{4}\label{eq4}$$

In addition, note that

$$\log x \lt 0 \text{ for } 0 \lt x \lt 1 \tag{5}\label{eq5}$$

Thus, using \eqref{eq4}, we get

$$\left(a - 1\right)\log x \leq 0 \tag{6}\label{eq6}$$

giving that

$$e^{\left(a - 1\right)\log x} \leq 1 \Rightarrow e^{\left(a - 1\right)\log x} - 1 \leq 0 \tag{7}\label{eq7}$$

Putting this and \eqref{eq3} into \eqref{eq2}, using that you have a positive value multiplied by a value which is $0$ or negative, gives that

$$x^a - x \leq 0 \Rightarrow x^a \leq x \tag{8}\label{eq8}$$

I hope I haven't used any properties I'm not supposed to.

Nothing above is specific to using a base of $e$ as the statements just use a basic property of logarithms that $\log x \lt 0$ if $x \lt 1$, and that the base to any negative power is $\lt 1$, so any other positive base, e.g., $10$, could have been used instead.